# Button not clickable due to overlapping view

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

This might be an easy solution but for some reason I couldn't find the solution online.

I have two views. One view is a grid and the other is a button. The Grid View is showing different views (boxview, label, etc..)

But underneath it is a button view. But this view is not included in the Grid View. I cannot put it inside the Grid View because of reasons. I just wanted to know if there's a possibility for it to be clickable without moving the views or even if there's a view on top of it?

Here's how it looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ContentView
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="PlayUIArea.NotificationConfirmView">
    <ContentView.Content>
        <Grid BackgroundColor="Blue">
            <BoxView
                WidthRequest="100"
                VerticalOptions="Fill"
                HorizontalOptions="Start"
                BackgroundColor="Black" />
            <Button Text="Confirm"
                        OnClick="Button_Click"
                        VerticalOptions="Start"
                        HorizontalOptions="Center" />
            <Grid BackgroundColor="Red" Margin="100,0,0,0" Padding="-100,0,0,0">
                <Label Text="Label Here"
                       HorizontalOptions="Center"
                       VerticalOptions="Center" />

            </Grid>

        </Grid>
    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

Is there anyway to make this clickable?

Answer (score 1):

I am a bit late but I think I found a solution to this.

```
<Grid>
    <WebView Grid.Row ="1" Source="[insert random embedded youtube source]"/>
        
    <RelativeLayout Grid.Row ="1" InputTransparent="True" CascadeInputTransparent="False">
          <Button CornerRadius="0" Command="{Binding GoToVideoFullscreen}"
                RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=0.8}"
                RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Factor=0.9}"
                RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=Constant, Constant=17}"
                RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=Constant, Constant=17}"/>
    </RelativeLayout> 
</Grid>
```

I had a similar problem, where I wanted to overlap a WebView with a custom button. But my RelativeLayout, which I used to place the button was eating all the inputs and the WebView could not be used anymore.

So I added `InputTransparent="True"` and `CascadeInputTransparent="False"` to the `RelativeLayout`. The `InputTransparent="True"` makes it invisible to inputs, the `CascadeInputTransparent="False"` prevents the `InputTransparent` value from inheriting to the children (in this case my button).

Documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.visualelement.inputtransparent?view=xamarin-forms

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.layout.cascadeinputtransparent?view=xamarin-forms

Answer (score 0):

Agree with  @G.Mich , you should put all of elements in one layout . For example you can put them in a `StackLayout`

```
<ContentPage.Content>
   <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
      <Button Onclick="Button_Clicked" /> <!-- This isn't clickable -->
      <Grid>
         your code here
      </Grid>      
   </StackLayout> 
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Comment: Zhang. I have edited here too. Sorry, I was taken from a meeting.

Comment: I think because of you didn't set the `Grid.Row` . So all of elements will overlap .You need to set the layout of Grid .

Answer (score -4):

place the `button` on top of the `Grid` by placing it after the Grid in the XAML

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <Grid>
         My code here
    </Grid>
    <Button Onclick="Button_Clicked" /> <!-- This isn't clickable -->
</ContentPage.Content>
```